# Hydrating (SSR/Prefetching) Nextjs13 is not working with react-query/tanstack-query

Tags: next.js, react-query

I try to build my own blog by using nextjs 13.4 app router with Tanstack query.
What i want to achieve is to have pagination with tanstack query and it is working now.
but since it is client side rendering, i want to implement prefetch data by using prefetchQuery from tanstack query.

how i implement the code is
layout.tsx << providers << HydratedBlogList << BlogList

here is code for each file.

1.layout.tsx

```
import './globals.css'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import { Navbar } from '../components/Navbar'
import { Footer } from '../components/Footer'
import Script from 'next/script'
import { ReactNode } from "react";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })


export const metadata = {
  title: 'Haikal Blog',
  description: 'Blog created by haikal to share his knowledge with the world',
  metadataBase: new URL('https://farhienza-haikal.my.id'),
  alternates: {
    canonical: '/',
    languages: {
      'en-US': '/en-US',
      'id-ID': '/id-ID',
    },
  },
}


export default function RootLayout({ children }: {children: ReactNode}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className=''>
        <section><Navbar /></section>
        <section className='md:mx-10 lg:mx-15 xl:mx-20'>{children}</section>
        <section><Footer /></section>
        <Script strategy="lazyOnload" src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-K9JFYBBM5Z'
        />
        <Script id='google-analyics-script' strategy="lazyOnload">
          {`window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)};
          gtag('js', new Date());
           gtag('config', 'G-K9JFYBBM5Z');`}
        </Script>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

2. page.tsx

```
import Featured from '@/components/Featured'
import BlogListWithPagination from '@/components/BlogList'
import Providers from './utils/Providers';
import HydratedPosts from '@/components/HydratedBlogList';
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from '@tanstack/react-query-devtools';

export interface Props {
  data: PropsDatum[];
  meta: Meta;
  slug: string;
}

export interface PropsDatum {
  id: number;
  attributes: PurpleAttributes;
}

export interface PurpleAttributes {
  title: string;
  slug: string;
  content: string;
  featured: boolean;
  createdAt: string;
  updatedAt: string;
  altthumbnail: string;
  descriptions: null | string;
  thumbnail: Thumbnail;
}

export interface Thumbnail {
  data: ThumbnailDatum[];
}

export interface ThumbnailDatum {
  id: number;
  attributes: FluffyAttributes;
}

export interface FluffyAttributes {
  name: string;
  alternativeText: null | string;
  caption: null;
  width: number;
  height: number;
  formats: Formats;
  hash: string;
  ext: string;
  mime: string;
  size: number;
  url: string;
  previewUrl: null;
  provider: string;
  provider_metadata: null;
  createdAt: string;
  updatedAt: string;
}

export interface Formats {
  thumbnail: Small;
  small: Small;
}

export interface Small {
  name: string;
  hash: string;
  ext: string;
  mime: string;
  path: null;
  width: number;
  height: number;
  size: number;
  url: string;
}

export interface Meta {
  pagination: Pagination;
}

export interface Pagination {
  page: number;
  pageSize: number;
  pageCount: number;
  total: number;
}

const page = async ({ data, meta }: Props) => {
  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col w-auto mx-0 mt-5 space-y-5'>
      <Providers>
      </Providers>
    </div>
  )
};

export default page;
```

3. providers

```
'use client';

import BlogListWithPagination from '@/components/BlogList'
import Featured from '@/components/Featured'
import HydratedPosts from '@/components/HydratedBlogList';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query'
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from '@tanstack/react-query-devtools'
import React from 'react'


export interface Props {
    data: PropsDatum[];
    meta: Meta;
    slug: string;
}

export interface PropsDatum {
    id: number;
    attributes: PurpleAttributes;
}

export interface PurpleAttributes {
    title: string;
    slug: string;
    content: string;
    featured: boolean;
    createdAt: string;
    updatedAt: string;
    altthumbnail: string;
    descriptions: null | string;
    thumbnail: Thumbnail;
}

export interface Thumbnail {
    data: ThumbnailDatum[];
}

export interface ThumbnailDatum {
    id: number;
    attributes: FluffyAttributes;
}

export interface FluffyAttributes {
    name: string;
    alternativeText: null | string;
    caption: null;
    width: number;
    height: number;
    formats: Formats;
    hash: string;
    ext: string;
    mime: string;
    size: number;
    url: string;
    previewUrl: null;
    provider: string;
    provider_metadata: null;
    createdAt: string;
    updatedAt: string;
}

export interface Formats {
    thumbnail: Small;
    small: Small;
}

export interface Small {
    name: string;
    hash: string;
    ext: string;
    mime: string;
    path: null;
    width: number;
    height: number;
    size: number;
    url: string;
}

export interface Meta {
    pagination: Pagination;
}

export interface Pagination {
    page: number;
    pageSize: number;
    pageCount: number;
    total: number;
}


const Providers = async ({ data,meta }) => {
    const [queryClient] = React.useState(() => new QueryClient())

    return (
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
            <Featured data={data} meta={meta}></Featured>
            <HydratedBlogList></HydratedBlogList>
            <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
        </QueryClientProvider>
    )
}

export default Providers
```

4. hydratedbloglist

```
import { dehydrate } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import getQueryClient from '@/app/utils/getQueryClient';
import BlogListWithPagination from './BlogList';
import ReactQueryHydrate from '@/app/utils/HydrateClient';
import { dataPagination } from '@/app/api/fetch';

const HydratedBlogList = async () => {
    const queryClient = getQueryClient()

    await queryClient.prefetchQuery({
        queryKey: ['projects', 1],
        queryFn: () => dataPagination,
    })

    const dehydratedState = dehydrate(queryClient);

    return (
        <ReactQueryHydrate>
            <BlogListWithPagination />
        </ReactQueryHydrate>
    );
};
export default HydratedBlogList;
```

5. bloglist

```
"use client";

import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/image";
import {
  Card,
  CardContent,
  CardDescription,
  CardFooter,
  CardHeader,
  CardTitle,
} from "@/components/ui/card"
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { dataBloglist } from "@/app/api/fetch";
import { dataPagination } from "@/app/api/fetch";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider, useQuery, dehydrate, Hydrate } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from '@tanstack/react-query-devtools'
import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import { useState } from "react";
import PageButton from "@/components/PageButton";

export interface Props {
  data: PropsDatum[];
  meta: Meta;
}

export interface PropsDatum {
  id: number;
  attributes: PurpleAttributes;
}

export interface PurpleAttributes {
  title: string;
  slug: string;
  content: string;
  featured: boolean;
  createdAt: string;
  updatedAt: string;
  altthumbnail: string;
  descriptions: null | string;
  thumbnail: Thumbnail;
  tags: Propstags;
}

export interface Thumbnail {
  data: ThumbnailDatum[];
}

export interface ThumbnailDatum {
  id: number;
  attributes: FluffyAttributes;
}

export interface FluffyAttributes {
  name: string;
  alternativeText: null | string;
  caption: null;
  width: number;
  height: number;
  formats: Formats;
  hash: string;
  ext: string;
  mime: string;
  size: number;
  url: string;
  previewUrl: null;
  provider: string;
  provider_metadata: null;
  createdAt: string;
  updatedAt: string;
}

export interface Formats {
  thumbnail: Small;
  small: Small;
}

export interface Small {
  name: string;
  hash: string;
  ext: string;
  mime: string;
  path: null;
  width: number;
  height: number;
  size: number;
  url: string;
}

export interface Meta {
  pagination: Pagination;
}

export interface Pagination {
  page: number;
  pageSize: number;
  pageCount: number;
  total: number;
}

export interface UpperPrpos {
  props: Props;
}

export interface Propstags {
  data: Datum[];
  meta: Meta;
}

export interface Datum {
  id: number;
  attributes: Attributes;
}

export interface Attributes {
  name_tag: string;
  createdAt: Date;
  updatedAt: Date;
}


const queryClient = new QueryClient()


const BlogList: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const pageSize = 6;
  const fetchProjects = () => {
    // Function body
    return fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_URL +
      `/api/posts?populate=*&pagination[page]=${page}&pagination[pageSize]=${pageSize}&sort=createdAt:desc`)
      .then((res) => res.json());
  };

  const {
    isLoading,
    isError,
    error,
    isPreviousData,
    isFetching,
    data
  } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['projects',page],
    queryFn: () => fetchProjects(),
    keepPreviousData: true
  })

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  if (isError) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;

  }
  const nextPage = () => setPage(prev => prev + 1);
  const prevPage = () => setPage(prev => prev - 1);
  const pagesArray = Array(data.meta.pagination.pageCount).fill(0).map((_, index) => index + 1);
  console.log("titit", data);
  console.log(isError)
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="h-auto w-auto mx-auto flex flex-col">
        <div className="container grid grid-cols-1 mx-auto space-y-5 md:grid-cols-2 lg:space-y-0">
          {data.data.map((post) => (
            <div className="flex flex-col" key={post.id}>
              <CardTitle className="m-6">
                <Link href={"/blog/" + post.attributes.slug}>
                  <h2 className="card-title">{post.attributes.title}</h2>
                </Link>
                <div className="flex flex-row"> {/* Wrap the tags in a single div with flex layout */}
                  {post.attributes.tags.data.map((tag) => (
                    <div className="flex flex-row" key={tag.id}> {/* Use a single div for each tag */}
                      <Link href={"/tags?q=" + tag.attributes.name_tag}>
                        <Button className="w-auto h-auto">
                          {tag.attributes.name_tag.replace(/-/g, ' ')}
                        </Button>
                      </Link>
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </div>
              </CardTitle>
              <CardContent className="">
                <div className="h-24 overflow-hidden">{post.attributes.content}</div>
              </CardContent>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className="container mx-auto px-auto">
          <div className="join flex justify-center">
            <Button className="join-item" variant="outline" onClick={prevPage} disabled={isPreviousData || page === 1}>&lt;&lt;</Button>
            {pagesArray.map(pg => <PageButton key={pg} pg={pg} setPage={setPage} isPreviousData={isPreviousData || page === pg} />)}
            <Button className="join-item" variant="outline" onClick={nextPage} disabled={isPreviousData || page === data.meta.pagination.pageCount}>&gt;&gt;</Button>
          </div>
          <div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const BlogListWithPagination = () => (
  <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
    <BlogList/>
    <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
  </QueryClientProvider>
);

export default BlogListWithPagination;
```

I also have several supporting code (form what i learned from youtube)

1. HydrateClient

```
"use client";

import { Hydrate as RQHydrate, HydrateProps} from '@tanstack/react-query'

import React from 'react'

const ReactQueryHydrate = (props: HydrateProps) => {
  return (
    <RQHydrate {...props}/>
  )
}

export default ReactQueryHydrate
```

2. getqueryclient

```
import {cache} from 'react';
import {QueryClient} from '@tanstack/react-query';

const getQueryClient = cache(() => new QueryClient());


export default getQueryClient;
```

here is the error result:

```
- error Error: Not implemented.
    at HydratedPosts (./components/HydratedBlogList.tsx:19:94)
- wait compiling...
- event compiled client and server successfully in 13.9s (869 modules)
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gsijb.png)

Answer (score 1):

`HydratedBlogList` seems to be a server component, because it's async, but it is used below a client boundary (`'use client'`), so this cannot work.

In order to be able to import server component from client component, you have to pass them down as `children` though the `<Providers>` component, like [the docs](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/ssr#using-the-app-directory-in-nextjs-13) show:

```
// app/providers.jsx
'use client'

import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query'

export default function Providers({ children }) {
  const [queryClient] = React.useState(() => new QueryClient())

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>{children}</QueryClientProvider>
  )
}
tsx
// app/layout.jsx
import Providers from './providers'

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head />
      <body>
        <Providers>{children}</Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

In your case, that would be:

```
const page = async ({ data, meta }: Props) => {
  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col w-auto mx-0 mt-5 space-y-5'>
      <Providers>
        <HydratedBlogList />
      </Providers>
    </div>
  )
};
```

That way, you can pass `HydratedBlogList` as a server component from a server component (your page) *through* a client component (Providers). Otherwise, every child of a client component must be a client component as well.